# Redraw matplotlib canvas without hanging/freezing GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, qthread

I am working on an application that plots data in real time.

I've used PyQt5 to create the GUI and Matplotlib to create the graphs.

The GUI consists of a window with multiple tabs.
There are currently 4 tabs and all of them have a grid layout.
The grid is 2x3, and the widgets that contain the graphs are
in locations (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), and (1, 0).

I am parsing the data, and processing it, in a separate thread.
The data is then passed to the widget that contains the graphs
and the graphs are cleared and then redrawn.

I believe that the hang/freeze is due to the
redrawing that is done within the main thread which contains my GUI.
This is what I've gathered from reading other questions, but
I have not seen a working solution to the given problem.

Is there any way that the drawing process can be done within a
separate thread so that it does not hang/freeze the GUI?

If there is no solution, is there another plotting library that is thread-safe and would be a good substitute for what I am trying to do?

I have not had any success in finding examples that solve this problem,
or good answers that I fully understand to address it.

Here is a related post in which I do not understand the provided answer as I cannot
get the code to execute.
[matplotlib and pyqt4: update plot in one thread, draw in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294145/matplotlib-and-pyqt4-update-plot-in-one-thread-draw-in-another)

Below is an example of what I currently have.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    pyqtSignal, 
    QThread, 
    QObject, 
    )

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
import time
import random


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)
        
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab1_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    
        GraphWidget_1 = GraphWidget()
        GraphWidget_2 = GraphWidget()
        GraphWidget_3 = GraphWidget()
        GraphWidget_4 = GraphWidget()
        
        self.tab1_layout.addWidget(GraphWidget_1, 0, 0)
        self.tab1_layout.addWidget(GraphWidget_2, 0, 1)
        self.tab1_layout.addWidget(GraphWidget_3, 1, 0)
        self.tab1_layout.addWidget(GraphWidget_4, 1, 1)
        
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1_layout)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab1")
    
class GraphWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        vertical_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize = (4,4), dpi = 100)  
        self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)

        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        
        self.canvas.figure = self.fig
        
        self.worker_obj = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker_obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker_obj.update_graph_signal.connect(self.update_graph)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker_obj.perpetual_update)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def update_graph(self, x, y):
        print('update')
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(x, y, color="orange")
        self.canvas.draw()

class Worker(QObject):
    
    update_graph_signal = pyqtSignal(list, list)
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def perpetual_update(self):
        
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
                    
            x = []
            y = []
            
            for i in range(0,3):
                n = random.randint(1,30)
                x.append(n)
                n = random.randint(1,30)
                y.append(n)
                            

            self.update_graph_signal.emit(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showMaximized()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: What I have done to get around matplotlib not being thread safe is use multiprocessing instead. Then if I want to pass data back to my main window to plot the data live time, you can use the multiprocessing queue to pass the data back to the main window. I usually use a QTimer to check if there's data in the queue on a refresh cycle that doesn't lag my mainwindow too much.

Comment: Does that help solve the main issue where the hang/freeze occurs during the redraw?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what causes your freezing/hanging. Usually when the GUI freezes it's because the main event loop is doing something that takes a long time. For example if you connected a button to a method in your class that has a while True: that will freeze your GUI forever. But if you call that same method in a thread or multiprocess it will still run that forever, but your GUI will still be able to continue the event loop.

Comment: Since matplotlib is not thread safe it usually needs to run from the main or else multiple threads end up trying to overwrite each other when adding data to the plot. Doing the plotting in a multiprocess allows you to have multiple instances of matplotlib which acts as a thread but has a diffferent memory space so they don't overwrite one another

Comment: I would use the multiprocess queue to pass the plot back to the mainwindow class, if the actual matplotlib plot object can't be passed I would either pass it the image data or a path to a saved image locally. that way when you plot the data in these different tabs nothing is stepping over each other and you can look for new data in the multiprocess queue with a timer and update the plots that way

Comment: also googling thread safe plotting libraries shows this as the first result: https://pypi.org/project/dvg-pyqtgraph-threadsafe/

Comment: Thank you. I may try to use pyqtgraph. In the posted code. I believe that the clear(), plot(), and draw() are hanging the GUI.

Comment: Are you able to provide a quick example using the multiprocess queue method on the code I've provided? It would help me learn faster.

Comment: I just ran your code and I don't see your GUI hanging/freezing? It's taking some time to update the plots, but I can still drag the window around while it's updating. If the main gui was really frozen from the code, then the mainwindow wouldn't be able to be dragged or re-sized or anything

Comment: Strange, it happens on my pc. When I drag it for a split second it hangs. During every update.

Comment: Throwing in QApplication.processEvents() after each line in the update_graph method allowed me to reduce/eliminate the hang.